# How to display toolbar/pager in place of breadcrumbs at the top in magento category view page?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I want to display the toolbar/pager in place of breadcrumbs, I have removed breadcrumbs, but I am not able to display the toolbar/pager in place of breadcrumbs. How to do that? I've tried putting xml blocks, and

```
<?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml(); ?>
```

Even though I am not getting it. Please anybody can help.

Comment: My page is 2column-left.phtml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't just call this method inside other template. `getToolbarHtml()` method is declared inside `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List` class and could be called only from it or from template which is assigned to it (that's how it works in default template).

I think you could try to create new `catalog/product_list` block under root reference in your layout file, set it different name and template. For example:

```
<reference name="root">
    <block type="catalog/product_list" name="top-pager" template="path/to/new/template/file.phtml" />
</reference>
```

which will contain only `<?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml(); ?>` call.

Then, inside `2columns-left.phtml` call it with `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('top-pager') ?>`. 
Also you could try to achieve it with some css.

Comment: Ok, I got it. The default template. thnx @nevermourn ..!!